# using angularjs, how do I dynamically add an input tag to a form based on the state of another input tag in the same form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am constructing a form in Angularjs. Based on the value of a radio button in the form, I want to change the number of options in another set of radio buttons. This is very easy using direct DOM manipulation, but I cannot see how to do it in angular.

I imagine that the solution lies in making the second set of radio buttons a directive, but I don't see how to communicate the state of the first set of radio buttons to the directive.

Comment: Also if you think its very easy to do with direct DOM, using angularjs will be 10 times easier

Comment: Hi, why don't you bind your second set of radio buttons to an array of literal objects in your scope ? Then, you just use "ng-repeat" on this array to display your radios buttons. Afterwards, you use "ng-click" on your first set of radio button and depending on the value of it, you add/remove an element in your array. Edit: Of course, if this is always the same modification (like add/remove a fixed number of radio button), you can simply use a ng-if) as "Subin" said.

Comment: Here is a code-pen http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/iBhoJ which show and hide the content

Comment: Subin - what would using ngIf look like. Would the ngIf attribute be on each radio button tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skoold2003/5d6by20v/1/) that may have what you're looking for. If not I can modify it a bit.

In `yourfile.html`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, how many radio buttons!
  <br />

  <form name="form1">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="optionCount" ng-change="optionsUpdated()" ng-value="0">0
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="optionCount" ng-change="optionsUpdated()" value="1">1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="optionCount" ng-change="optionsUpdated()" value="2">2
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
     <input type="radio" ng-model="optionCount" ngchange="optionsUpdated()" value="3">3
  </label>
  <br/>
  </form>
  <hr> 
  There should be {{optionCount}} radio buttons!
  <br />
  <form name="form2">
    <div ng-repeat="radio in radioArray">
      <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myOptions" value="1">Option {{$index + 1}}
      </label>
     <br/>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

And in `yourfile.js`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.numOpts = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  $scope.optionCount = 0;
  $scope.optionsUpdated = function() {
    var optionNum = Number($scope.optionCount)
    $scope.radioArray = new Array(optionNum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to make the value of the checkbox controll the  input field just create a scope that the two will communicate [can use the default]

use **$scope.modelCheckbox** for the checkbox and **$scope.modelInput** for the input and set the input disabled on the value change in **$scope.modelCheckbox**

Its typical angular use using model binding so you will get more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)